# Python categorize and create new columns from CSV full addresses

Tags: python, pandas

How to categorize and create new columns from full addresses?

The address string is comma separated and use those keywords:

*district

*city

*borough

*village

*municipality

*county

The source full address format can look like this:

```
col1;col2;fulladdress
data1_1;data2_1;Some district, Cityname, Some county
data1_2;data2_2;Another village, Another municipality, Another county
data1_3;data2_3;Third city, Third county
data1_4;data2_4;Forth borough, Forth municipality, Forth county
```

There is one peculiarity with one city in particular - This city is called "Clause" and sometimes it is wrote out as format of: "Clause city" and sometimes it is just "Clause" in full address string.

For example:

```
Clause city, Third county
Seventh district, Clause, Seventh municipality
```

So, I want to categorize only one version format which is "Clause city" to avoid duplicate output. So, if there is "Clause" alone in full address string, it should be renamed to "Clause city" in CSV.

The source data file is called data.csv and exported.csv for the categorized version.

All I have is this:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv', delimiter=';')

address = df.fulladdress.str.split(',', expand=True)

district = df[df.fulladdress.str.match('district')]
city = df[df.fulladdress.str.match('city')]
borough = df[df.fulladdress.str.match('borough')]
village = df[df.fulladdress.str.match('village')]
municipality = df[df.fulladdress.str.match('municipality')]
county = df[df.fulladdress.str.match('county')]

df.to_csv('exported.csv', sep=';', encoding='utf8', index=True)

print ("Done!")
```

Answer (score 0):

If there is only one problem city, I think you could use replace?

raw csv data:

```
Some district, Cityname, Some county
Another village, Another municipality, Another county
Third city, Third county
Forth borough, Forth municipality, Forth county
Clause city, Third county
Seventh district, Clause, Seventh municipality
```

replace solution:

```
df = pd.read_csv('clause.csv', names=['district', 'city', 'country'], sep=',')

# need to strip white space for replace to work
df = df.apply(lambda x: x.str.strip())

df.replace('Clause', 'Clause city', inplace=True)
```

output:

```
    district              city                     country
0   Some district         Cityname                 Some county
1   Another village       Another municipality     Another county
2   Third city            Third county             NaN
3   Forth borough         Forth municipality       Forth county
4   Clause city           Third county             NaN
5   Seventh district      Clause city              Seventh municipality
```